# What are the real Electromagnetic fields of Circularly Polarized Light?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, polarization, chirality, helicity

It is my understanding that the $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ fields of a circularly polarized photon sit purely in the $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$ representation of the Lorentz Group, and have helicity $-1$, and $+1$ respectively. These states are described by field configurations which satisfy $$E=\pm iB$$

Clearly the Faraday tensor of these states is not real. Given that classical physics is described by a strictly real representation of the Lorentz group, how do circularly polarized fields actually appear as real, measurable fields?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between the structure of plane and circularly polarized light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/497580/what-is-the-difference-between-the-structure-of-plane-and-circularly-polarized-l)

Comment: Not quite, I don't completely understand how a phase difference leads to a field which is either self dual or anti-self dual. I.e. how we can have a real field which is purely left or right chiral

Comment: How classical fields emerge from quantum field theory, QED is a quantum field theory, is discussed here and  it is not simple, https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html

Comment: @anna v, thank you for the link. Though I'm not entirely sure my question is completely quantum field theoretic in nature. It can be posed entirely as "There are no real representations of Dual or Anti-self dual Faraday fields in Minkiwski spacetime. Given this, is "Circularly polarized light" a misnomer?"

Comment: I cannot answer this, (as an experimental particle physicist) I just know that photons (quantum mechanics)  are not light (classical EM), they build up light https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_angular_momentum_of_light . I think the answer needs QED.

Comment: This relation can be understood purely classical as a relation on the positive frequency part of the Fourier transformed E and B fields (the negative frequency parts are implied by the reality of the position space fields). I don't think the close votes as duplicates are warranted, as this questions asks not for what circularly polarized light is, but how the given equation describes it.

Comment: (I am working on an answer, please don't close before I worked through the math ;) )

Comment: @SebastianRiese In the future, please only use comments for their intended purpose: to ask for clarification or offer suggestions to improve the post. Also, note that whether or not a user is working on an answer is not grounds to keep a question open. In fact, that opposes the current close policy, as the point of closing questions is to prevent new answers. If you think the question should be closed, consider flagging / voting to close instead of trying to squeeze in an answer before the question closes. If you think it should be open, just post an answer.

Comment: @BioPhysicist One can't selectively vote to keep open, if the review queue is too large I simply won't reach that question when working through my 20 votes a day. And arguing about the reasons to close/not close a question is indeed a valid use of comments IMO (and is often seen). The second comment was more or less a joke – which is not really considered a good use of comments, but is also widely practised (and often heavily upvoted). Perhaps we can ask meta about it (or find an existing verdict); I'd be happy to see the consensus of the community on the issue!

Answer (score 0):

This formula can even be understood at a purely classical level if you take the $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ in your equation to be the positive frequency parts of the Fourier transforms $\tilde{\vec E}(\omega, \vec k)$ and $\tilde{\vec B}(\omega, \vec k)$.

The reality of $\vec E(t, \vec r)$ and $\vec B(t, \vec r)$ becomes a set of conditions like $\tilde{\vec B}(\omega)^* = \tilde{\vec B}(-\omega)$ (and so on for the other variables) in Fourier space. So you can restrict the domain of your frequency and wave vector variables to the positive frequency domain (and the negative frequency components are implied by the reality condition).

Now, if you start with a circularly polarized plane wave $\vec B(\vec r, t) = \vec e_x B \cos(\Omega t - K z) \pm \vec e_y B \sin(\Omega t - K z)$, you get the following in positive frequency Fourier space (w.l.o.g. $\vec k = k \vec e_x$)${}^1$:
\begin{align*}
 \tilde{\vec B} &= B \vec e_x  \left( \frac 1 2 \delta(\Omega - \omega) \frac 1 2 \delta(k - K) - \frac 1 {2i} \delta(\Omega - \omega) \frac 1 {2i} \delta(k - K) \right) \\
&\phantom{{}={}} \pm B\vec e_y \left( \frac 1 {2i} \delta(\Omega - \omega) \frac 1 2 \delta(k - K) - \frac 1 {2} \delta(\Omega - \omega) \frac 1 {2i} \delta(k - K) \right) \\
&= \frac 1 2 B ( \vec e_x  \pm i \vec e_y  ) \delta(\Omega - \omega) \delta(k - K)
\end{align*}

The corresponding $\tilde{\vec E} = \pm i \tilde{\vec B}$ is
\begin{align*}
 \tilde{\vec E} &= \frac 1 2  ( \pm i \vec e_x - \vec e_y ) \delta(\Omega - \omega) \delta(k - K)
\end{align*}

Transforming $\tilde{\vec E}$ back to real space (this can be done by analogy to the above) one obtains
$$ \vec E(t, \vec r) = \pm \vec e_x B \sin\left(\Omega t - K z \right) - \vec e_y B \cos\left(\Omega t - K z\right) $$
which is exactly the circularly polarized plane wave that complements $\vec B$  as a solution the vacuum Maxwell equations:
$$ \vec e_z \times \vec E = \pm \vec e_y B \sin(\Omega t - Kz) + \vec e_x B \cos(\Omega t - Kz) = \vec B$$

The computation works almost the same when including a phase offset $\phi$.

And this generalizes naturally to wave packets, etc. due to the linearity of the Maxwell equations.

The connection to QED is simply that solutions to the classical field equations describe possible modes of the quantum EM field.

${}^1$ the Fourier transform can be read off after using the addition theorems and the Fourier transforms of $\cos$ and $\sin$.